Xcode: Local repository out of date: Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again
Command Line Error:

tarunshomefolder@Taruns-MBP Capture-main % git status
On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)


Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged ..." to unstage)
modified:   Capture.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/tarunshomefolder.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate


Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   Capture.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/tarunshomefolder.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate


tarunshomefolder@Taruns-MBP Capture-main %

I've done a lot, restarted Xcode, cloned the project made a new repository, etc. I am not great with the command line but know the basics. I've tried merging branches and fixing it but i've had to use a commit from 2 days ago which is pretty old code in terms of my current project. I've already had to redo the code twice and I don't know how to get rid of this problem so I can just commit and push my data onto github.
